# UnboundLocalError while using += but not append list

Tags: python, list, append

I do not quite understand the difference between the following two similar codes:

```
def y(x):
    temp=[]
    def z(j):
        temp.append(j)
    z(1)
    return temp
```

calling `y(2)` returns `[1]`

```
def y(x):
    temp=[]
    def z(j):
        temp+=[j]
    z(1)
    return temp
```

calling `y(2)` returns `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'temp' referenced before assignment`. Why `+` operator generates the error? Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Answer to the heading, the difference between + and "append" is:

```
[11, 22] + [33, 44,]
```

will give you:

```
[11, 22, 33, 44]
```

and.

```
b = [11, 22, 33]
b.append([44, 55, 66])
```

will give you

```
[11, 22, 33 [44, 55, 66]]
```

**Answer to the error**

> This is because when you make an assignment to a variable in a scope, that variable becomes local to that scope and shadows any similarly named variable in the outer scope

The problem here is `temp+=[j]` is equal to `temp = temp +[j]`. The temp variable is read here before its assigned. This is why it's giving this problem. This is actually covered in python FAQ's.

For further readings, click [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/15/understanding-unboundlocalerror-in-python). :)

Comment: Your first part shows that `+=` is more like `extend` than `append`.  But `+=` isn't exactly like `temp=temp+[]`.  In one the `id` changes, in the other it does not.  The `iadd` docs claim that `x.__iadd__(y) <==> x+=y`. But apparently the scoping rule applies first.  So that equivalence isn't exact either.

Answer (score 3):

The `UnboundLocalError` occurs because, when you make an assignment to a variable in a scope, that variable is automatically considered by Python to be *local to that scope* and shadows any similarly named variable in any outer scope.

In the `append` function, you are not making an assignment *per se*, and therefore there is no scope error.